# How to Implement Product Image Change on Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I am creating a shopping cart that should contain product thumbnails in single column in a  left side column and a main product image. If you hover the mouse over a thumbnail image, the main image should replaced with the image from thumbnail.

This should be like in Amazon in [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0057OCDQS/ref=s9_simh_gw_p422_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=1ZQ6JXTTST3W87ZTQE26&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=470938811&pf_rd_i=507846](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0057OCDQS). How do I implement this? Is there some control or jQuery plugin for this? If not, where can I find a code sample?

jQuery, jQuery UI, ASP.NET/Mono MVC3 are used.

[image: amazon image hover]

**Update**

Thumbnail list is very big. How to show only 3 thumbnails and add up and down scroll buttons which can select previous and next thumb. Something like:

```
scroll one thumb up

thumbnail image 1

thumbnail image 2

thumbnail image 3

scroll one thumb up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method for that

HTML:

```html
<div class="thumbs">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/sports/200/400" width="50" height="50"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/city/200/400" width="50" height="50"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/people/200/400" width="50" height="50"/>
</div>

<div class="main-img">
    <img id="main" src="http://lorempixel.com/people/200/400"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.thumbs {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.thumbs img {
    display: block;
}

.main-img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JQuery:

```jquery
$('.thumbs img').hover(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#main').attr('src', url);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFu52/1/)

Comment: Thnk you very much. This works. Unfortunately thumbnail list can be very big. How to show only 3 thumbs and add up and down scroll buttons which retrieve thums from database ? I updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<img src="img/myimage_tb.png" data-src="img/myimage.png">
<script>
    $('.productImage').hover(function(){
         $(this).data('thb') = this.src;
         this.src = $(this).data('src');
      },function(){
         this.src = $(this).data('thb');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thnk you. Thumbnail list can be big. How to show only 3 thumbnails in screen, add scroll buttons and load previous/next thumb from server if those buttons are pressed ? I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just change the html of the div using the Jquery onClick ?

Comment: Image needs to be changed if mouse cursor is over thumbnail, witohut click. I*m looking for a way how to save images in page and show specific image is move is over thumbnail.